# Scaling Return Structures of C++ Functions Systematically

Tags: c++, function, class, c++17

I have a couple functions that return not just one variable, but a collection of variables. For example, a root finder might return the found root, iterations needed, and whether the root-finding process was indeed successful.

```
struct ReturnData { 
    const double root;
    const size_t iterations;
    const bool success;
};

template <class FuncType>
ReturnData findRoot(const FuncType& f, const double& guess) {
    double root = guess;
    size_t iterations = 0;

    while(true) { /*... find root ...*/ }

    return { root, iterations, true };
}
```

Now this works if I am only returning a small number of variables. But maybe I want to include a possible error message like `const std::string errorMessage` in my `ReturnData`, as well as other reference meta data. So when scaling this to, say, more than 10 parameters, it starts to be very easy to make mistakes in using the initializer list to return the data. Maybe I also deleted a parameter, or I re-ordered them, etc. which in turn requires me to carefully apply the same changes to the initializer list at the end of function `findRoot`.

What is a good systematic approach to return data from a function like this? My criteria are:

1. Clear code that's straight-forward to understand/maintain by other people.
2. *Somewhat* efficient code, meaning that I don't want to construct overly elaborate return structures (since this root-finder might be called many many times, and in the majority of cases people will only care about variable `root` ).

Comment: This probably should go on [softwareengineering.se].

Comment: "*So when scaling this to, say, more than 10 parameters*" If you have 10 *independent* values to return, then your function is doing *way too much*. Right now, you have 3 values: the actual value of interest, a bit of supplemental data that matters if the value was generated, and an optional error if the operation could not be completed (which in theory ought to be an exception, or at least `expected`). Anything more than that, and you should seriously question how much stuff this function is doing and how important it is that the caller receive those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably just create a variable and set its members:

```
    //...

    ReturnData rd; 
    rd.root        = root;
    rd.iterations  = iterations;
    rd.success     = true;

    return rd;
};
```

I wouldn't worry about performance since there is RVO.

If you are overly concerned about performance you could declare a variable of `ReturnData` at the begin of your function and use its members:

```
template <typename FuncType>
ReturnData findRoot(FuncType const &f, double const &guess) {
    ReturnData rd;

    while( /* ... */ ) { /*...*/ rt.root = /*...*/; ++rd.iterations; }

    rd.success = true;
    return rd;
};
```

Comment: Provided compiler supports NRVO properly...

Comment: The question is tagged C++17, so guaranteed copy elision comes into play anyhow.

Comment: This makes sense, but I would have to make the variables in `ReturnData` non-const, which I'd rather not.

Comment: @lubgr all I was hinting at that to think about quality of implementation. I know two big players here one compiler tends to not do RVO and other avoids NRVO.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX may be you can use prototype concept?

Comment: well, even without RVO there won't be any difference to `return { root, iterations, true };` when the compiler does its job.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie What would that look like?

Comment: @Phil-ZXX class that can be constructed from one of preset initialized instances ("prototypes"), perhaps with a way to modify initialization by submitting some of those fields that can change, like in situation you described. That's usually viable for large classes that have one or only few starting states.

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because you can shoot yourself in the foot with this approach. If you add a new parameter, but don't update this function, the new parameter remains uninitialized. This can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: if you add a new member and don't update the constructor AND the function using the object you shoot yourself in the foot as well.

Comment: While I don't agree with the downvote, please note the strong coupling between that class and the function. Consider making a class with private members only and member functions like `found_root(z, iterations)` which properly updates the internal variables, whatever they are.

Comment: @Swordfish With the difference that if you properly update the class/struct, your compiler will trigger you at the calls, whereas with your approach it will never do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you have worries that the return value is not properly initialized, add a constructor that makes sure every necessary argument is passed to it. As the constructor now handles class invariants, the data members should not be public anymore, and you need getter methods. If this sounds overly complicated, you need to live with the risk that a return value could be improperly constructed. Or - keep the data members public and make them `const`. You loose the ability to assign to instances of this type, but this could be acceptable if you only initialize them upon invoking `findRoot`.

In terms of scaling, any solution will be opinionated, hence only my two cents: don't hesitate to add further `struct`s and include them as data members in `ReturnData`. Any group of parameters that can be grouped in a sensible way justifies a new type. Whenever information that the function returns should be optional, well, use `std::optional`. This is exactly what the type is about.

And finally, as you mentioned efficiency in the question as well - when you think there is a bottleneck, measure first. It's unlikely that `ReturnData` will slow down an application. Not only because return value optimziation, also because `findRoot` must be quite complex to gather so much data to return that the function itself will probably dominate any performance analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're targeting gcc and/or clang, you can use designated initializers:

```
return {
    .root = root,
    .iterations = iterations,
    .success = true
};
```

This was originally introduced in C99 and is planned for C++2a. Both gcc and clang support it as an extension, unfortunately MSVC doesn't.

Alternative approach could be using structures, as follows:

```
struct Root { double value; };
struct Iterations { size_t value; };
struct Success { bool value; };

struct ReturnData 
{
    const Root root;
    const Iterations iterations;
    const Success success;
};

// usage:
return {
    Root { root },
    Iterations { iterations },
    Success { true }
};
```

Comment: In you rexample to obtain the value, you need to do ReturnData.root.value, right? Aren't you kind of surpassing the idea of the struct?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to give the values unique types.
It's slightly tedious, but it works.
You can use a template to cut down on the tediousity.

Something along these lines:

```
template<typename T, typename>
struct NewType
{
    T value;
};

using Root = NewType<double, struct Root_T>;
using Success = NewType<bool, struct Success_T>;

struct ReturnData { 
    const Root root;
    const Success success;
};

template <class FuncType>
ReturnData findRoot(const FuncType& f, const double& guess) {
    double root = guess; 
    while(true) { /*... find root ...*/ }
    return { Root{root}, Success{true} }
}
```